# guava-parent 12th version jar is not downloading as expected

Tags: maven-3

In pom.xml,for guava-parent 12 i was added dependency as

com.google.guava
 guava-parent 12.0 pom

Build succeeded but jar is not downloaded as expected. While i check the repository path
i found the files as follows.

Maven repository path structure.

We tried to keep pom and jar.
The build got success, but the jar is not downloading. We did the same for guava-12 jar, the same jar has been downloaded as expected.

So, Can any one please help us to resolve such issue and give us a way to get the jar in the respective path.

Thanks in Advance.